# Jquery - $(this).length of checkboxes or radio buttons is always 1

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
<TD>
<input type="text" name="name1" size="35" class="mustEnter" />
</TD>

<TD>
<input type="radio" name="name2" value="val1" class="mustCheck"/>
<input type="radio" name="name2" value="val2" class="mustCheck"/>
<input type="radio" name="name2" value="val3" class="mustCheck"/>
</TD>

<TD>
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" value="valA" class="mustCheck"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" value="valB" class="mustCheck"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" value="valC" class="mustCheck"/>
</TD>
```

I want to test if the a mandatory field (in this case radio and check boxes) were checked, but it does not work.

`each()` passes through the radio buttons (or check boxes) three times and `$(this).length` is always 1.  I want to avoid testing by name as the list could be long. What would be the solution?

```
valid = true;
$("#studentForm input.mustEnter, #studentForm input.mustCheck").each(function() {
    if( ($(this).hasClass('mustEnter') && $(this).val() != false ) 
     || ($(this).hasClass('mustCheck') && $(this).length > 0) ) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("errorHighlight");
}
else { 
    $(this).parent().addClass('errorHighlight');
     valid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the way:**

As I have two classes, `mustEnter` for regular fields and `mustCheck` for radio and check-boxes, I use the mustCheck class to get the name of the element and then use the name to test if at least one in the group (of three in this case) was checked. I only need to use the `mustCheck` class in only one item of the group.

```
function validate_v3(frm) {
    valid = true;
    $("#studentForm input.mustEnter").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != false ) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("errorHighlight");
          }
        else { 
            $(this).parent().addClass('errorHighlight');
            valid = false;
          }
    });
    $("#studentForm input.mustCheck").each(function() {
        elmtName = $(this).attr("name");
        if ($("#studentForm input[name='"+elmtName+"']:checked").length > 0)  {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("errorHighlight");
          }
        else { 
            $(this).parent().addClass('errorHighlight');
            valid = false;
          }
    });
  return valid;
 } ;
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` within the `.each()` loop is always a SINGLE dom element - the current element being processed from the list of results from the main search. If you did

```
$('#studentFor input.mustEnter').length
```

you'd get the total count of all matching elements.

Comment: I need to check if any of the check boxes or radio button were checked as opposed to count all matching elements.

Comment: Then use `$('input.mustEnter:checked').length()`. There's no need for the looping and testing each individual element yourself.

Comment: In the example above, if radio is checked and check-box is not, `$('input.mustCheck:checked').length()` would give me 1, right?, how to remove the `errorHighlight` class from the checked one, and add it to the other?

Comment: This does not allow me to identify which one to error-hightlight and which one to make normal. I should have include the parent of each one from the beginning. I have just added the `<TD>` elements for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `.each`, `this` refers to the single item, not the collection. To access the collection, you probably want `$(this).parent().length`

Comment: No, `$(this).parent()` refers to the parent element of the current element.

Comment: Which is normally the collection, hence probably.

Comment: No. A dom node always has exactly one parent, with the exception of `document.documentElement`, whose parent is null.  Understand that 1.) `this` is a dom node, 2.) `$(this)` is a new jQuery object containing a single node (it knows nothing about any other jQuery objects that contain the same element), and 3.) `.parent()` is a wrapper that returns `element.parentNode`, which is a single element or null.

Comment: Agree, in this case the `parent()` wound be the table data element `<TD>` which is not shown in the example for simplicity.